# Error using relative paths in Alteryx when running through Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, alteryx

I have a Powershell script which calls an Alteryx analytic app (wizard) and inputs a single parameter into it via an .xml - method used to do this is [here](https://help.alteryx.com/2018.3/Command_Line.htm).

The output tools in the Alteryx workflow are setup as relative paths to store outputs to an *Input* and *Working* folder which are a level above the app itself, e.g.:

```
..\Input\FileName.yxdb
```

If I open up the Alteryx workflow and run it, or run the app via the interface, it works absolutely fine and my outputs are stored correctly. However, running it through Powershell using the code,

```
$modules = "C:\Projects\2019\Modules"
cd $modules
AlteryxEngineCmd.exe .\Extract_Variables.yxwz .\_Version.xml
```

returns the following errors:

```
Error - ToolId 5: Cannot access the folder .\Input\.
Error - ToolId 15: Cannot access the folder .\Working\.
Error - ToolId 24: Cannot access the folder .\Input\.
Error - ToolId 26: Cannot access the folder .\Input\.
```

despite the relative paths working fine if run directly inside the workflow. Powershell will run the Alteryx workflow okay but it fails to save the outputs.

As a test, I moved the *Input* and *Working* folders to the same level as the app itself and this worked fine - the files save to these test folders - so it is as if Powershell doesn't understand the two dots to represent moving up a level. In fact, I can write

```
..............\Input\FileName.yxdb
```

and it would still output to the test Input folder I created alongside the Alteryx app itself. Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Sounds like the app isn't reading your working directory properly.  I'd suggest using `Start-Process` and specifying the working directory where you need it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Are you able to provide an example of that for my process that would call my AlteryxEngineCmd.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to this which was a simple misunderstanding of syntax. My working directory is as follows:

```
- C:\Projects\2019
|-- Modules
    |-- AlteryxEngineCmd.exe
    |-- Extract_Variables.yxwz
    |-- _Version.xml
|-- Input
    |-- FileName.yxdb
|-- Working
```

The Alteryx wizard then needs calling in Powershell as follows:

```
$modules = "C:\Projects\2019\Modules"
cd $modules
AlteryxEngineCmd.exe Extract_Variables.yxwz _Version.xml
```

Notice there is no need for `.\` when calling the wizrd and the .xml file. Using `.\` will successfully call the module but effects relative paths set within it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment with an example of how to execute your app with `Start-Process`.  First, an assumption about file structure:

```
- C:\Projects\2019
|-- Modules
    |-- AlteryxEngineCmd.exe
    |-- Extract_Variables.yxwz
    |-- _Version.xml
|-- Input
    |-- FileName.yxdb
|-- Working
```

And code:

```
$processParams = @{
    FilePath         = '.\Modules\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe'
    ArgumentList     = '.\Modules\Extract_Variables.yxwz', '.\Modules\_Version.xml'
    WorkingDirectory = 'C:\Projects\2019'
    NoNewWindow      = $true
    Wait             = $true
    PassThru         = $true
}
Start-Process @processParams
```

Note: I've used a technique called splatting to pass all the parameters to `Start-Process` from a `hashtable` for readability.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting issues. If I run the script, the AlteryxEngineCmd.exe command window opens up but nothing else happens - as if it isn't being passed the ArgumentList parameters. I tried passing it a simpler workflow (not an app that needs .xml parameters) and this just opens and closes the cmd window, so I am getting mixed results.

Comment: I managed to fix this using my initial method. The problem was an unnecessary use of ` .\ ` when specifying my workflow and .xml file.